# Explain the output of the following code by describing the micro task queue and call stack architecture

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

**This is the code:**

```
function SSD() {
    console.log('SSD')
}

async function createData() {
    let status = undefined
    try {
        const res = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/Soumya-0x000')
        status = res.status
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('error')
    }
    return status
}  //Micro task queue has high priority

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(!undefined)
}, 1000);    //callback queue / task queue has low priority

SSD()

createData().then((code) => {
    console.log('Status code: ', code)
})

console.log('C')

Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('D'))    //Micro task queue has high priority

console.log('E')
```

**I thought output should look like:**

```
SSD
C
E
Status code:  200
D
true
```

**But actual output is:**

```
SSD
C
E
D
Status code:  200
true
```

API is ok.
Now please someone explain me, why and how 'D' is printed before 'Status code:  200' is printed.

**I'm expecting the output to be:**

```
SSD
C
E
Status code:  200
D
true
```

Because createData() is queued first inside micro task queue then it will come to the resolved promise. It is true that synchronous tasks are performed first and Promise is synchronous. But createData() comes first in micro task queue so it should be resolved first and `Status code:  200` should be printed first then `D`. But this is not happening.
Please explain........

Comment: `await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/Soumya-0x000')` is longer to execute (Network latency + execution time of the called API) than `Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('D'))` which is local and doesn't perform heavy tasks

Answer (score 0):

> But createData() comes first in micro task queue so it should be resolved first and Status code:  200 should be printed first then D

The callback function of `createData().then(...)` will be enqueued in the microtask queue only when the promise returned by the `createData` function is resolved. Until then, it is just registered as a fulfillment handler.

After the synchronous execution of your script ends, you have three promises:

- First one returned by `fetch` call
- Second one in pending state, returned by async `createData` function, and
- Third in resolved state returned by `Promise.resolve()`.

Second promise is dependent on the first promise and will only resolve once the first one resolves. On the other hand, the third promise is already resolved, as a result, its fulfillment handler is enqueued in the microtask queue first.